# Hiding searchbar hides navigation bar title also

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have `navigation bar` with `search` button. On the click on it it shows the `searchbar` and on cancel button click it hides. But for some reason if `searchbar` is hidden then the navigation bar titleview hides too. What could cause this? At first I actually wanted it to slide in from right to `titleView` but I couldn't achieve it so I made it like this.

This is the code to show it and to hide it:

```
//Create searchbar
    func createSearchBar(){

        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.184, green:0.996, blue:0.855, alpha:1.00)
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search brands"
        searchBar.delegate = self



        searchBar.hidden =  false
        searchBar.alpha = 0

        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(menuButton, animated: true)
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(searchButtton, animated: true)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.searchBar.alpha = 1
            }, completion: { finished in
                self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        })


    }

    //Searchbar hide
    func hideSearchBar() {


        navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(menuButton, animated: true)
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(searchButtton, animated: true)
        searchBar.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {


            }, completion: { finished in

        })
    }

    //Searchbar cancel button
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        hideSearchBar()
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        snusBrandsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: udpate screenshot if possible and if u want to show title then hide titleview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want set `title` of `navigationItem` on hiding of `searchBar` you need to set the `titleView` to nil and then set title.

```
func hideSearchBar() {
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(menuButton, animated: true)
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(searchButtton, animated: true)
    searchBar.alpha = 0
    self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
    self.navigationItem.title = "YourTitle"
}
```